# Comparing the function fminunc with the BFGS method for logistic regression

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave, cross-validation

I´m constructing an algorithm that uses the BFGS method to find the parameters in a logistic regression for a binary dataset in Octave.

Now, I´m struggling with something I believe is an overfitting problem. I run the algorithm for several datasets and it actually converges to the same results as the fminunc function of Octave. However for an especific "type of dataset" the algorithm converges to very high values of the parameters, at contrary to the fminunc which gives razonable values of these parameters. I added a regularization term and I actually achieved my algorithm to converge to the same values of fminunc.

This especific type of dataset has data that can be completely separated by a straight line. My question is: why this is a problem for the BFGS method but it´s not a problem for fminunc? How this function avoid this issue without regularization? Could I implement this in my algorithm?

The code of my algorithm is the following:

```
function [beta] = Log_BFGS(data, L_0)
clc 
close
%************************************************************************
%************************************************************************
%Loading the data:
[n, e] = size(data);
d = e - 1;
n; %Number of observations.
d; %Number of features.
Y = data(:, e); %Labels´ values
X_o = data(:, 1:d); 
X = [ones(n, 1) X_o]; %Features values            

%Initials conditions:
beta_0 = zeros(e, 1);

beta = [];
beta(:, 1) = beta_0;
N = 600; %Max iterations
Tol = 1e-10; %Tolerance
error = .1;
L = L_0; %Regularization parameter
B = eye(e);

options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 600);
[beta_s] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, Y, L)), beta_0, options);
disp('Beta obtained with the fminunc function');
disp("--------------");
disp(beta_s)

k = 1;
a_0 = 1;
% Define the sigmoid function
h = inline('1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z))'); 

while (error > Tol && k < N)
  beta_k = beta(:, k);
  x_0 = X*beta_k;
  h_0 = h(x_0);
  beta_r = [0 ; beta(:, k)(2:e, :)];
  g_k = ((X)'*(h_0 - Y) + L*beta_r)/n;
  d_k = -pinv(B)*g_k;
  a = 0.1; %I´ll implement an Armijo line search here (soon) 
  beta(:, k+1) = beta(:, k) + a*d_k;
  beta_k_1 = beta(:, k+1);
  x_1 = X*beta_k_1;
  h_1 = h(x_1);
  beta_s = [0 ; beta(:, k+1)(2:e, :)];
  g_k_1 = (transpose(X)*(h_1 - Y) + L*beta_s)/n;
  s_k = beta(:, k+1) - beta(:, k);
  y_k = g_k_1 - g_k;
  B = B - B*s_k*s_k'*B/(s_k'*B*s_k) + y_k*y_k'/(s_k'*y_k);
  k = k + 1;
  error = norm(d_k);
endwhile

%Accuracy of the logistic model:

p = zeros(n, 1);
for j = 1:n
  if (1./(1. + exp(-1.*(X(j, :)*beta(:, k)))) >= 0.5)
    p(j) = 1;
  else
    p(j) = 0;
  endif
endfor
R = mean(double(p == Y));
beta = beta(:, k);

%Showing the results:

disp("Estimation of logistic regression model Y = 1/(1 + e^(beta*X)),")
disp("using the algorithm BFGS =")
disp("--------------")
disp(beta)
disp("--------------")
disp("with a convergence error in the last iteration of:")
disp(error)
disp("--------------")
disp("and a total number of") 
disp(k-1) 
disp("iterations")
disp("--------------")
if k == N
  disp("The maximum number of iterations was reached before obtaining the desired error")
else
  disp("The desired error was reached before reaching the maximum of iterations")
endif
disp("--------------")
disp("The precision of the logistic regression model is given by (max 1.0):")
disp("--------------")
disp(R)
disp("--------------")

endfunction
```

The results I got for the dataset are showed in the following picture. If you need the data used in this situation, please let me know.

[Results of the algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZczGh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the objectives!

The values of the solution-vector are nice, but the whole optimization is driven by the objective.  You say `fminunc which gives reasonable values of these parameters`, but *reasonable* is not defined within this model.
It would not be impossible, that both, your low-value and your high-value solution allows pretty much the same objective. And that's what those solvers are solely caring about (when using no regulization-term).

So the important question is: is there a unique solution (which should disallow these results)? Only when your dataset has full rank! So maybe your data is rank-deficient and you obtain two equally good solutions. Of course there might be slight differences due to numerical-issues, which are always a source of errors, especially in more complex optimization-algorithms.

Comment: I understand your point. I have read that if data is linearly separable, weights of the model tend to go to infinity which leads to overfitting. Penalizing high weights with regularization can prevent this. The regularization parameter controls a tradeoff between fitting data well, and having well-regularized/small weights. Fminunc seems to avoid overfitting without regularization, and that's what I would like to figure out. When I use a proper value for L in the cost function, I get the same answer with my algorithm and fminunc.

Comment: I already gave my reasoning which covers your question. Don't compare the regularized with the unregularized model. Also: you compare two different algorithms, of course they will behave different if there would be multiple solutions (my conjecture). Probably Fminunc could also go for the *in your mind bad solution* with different learning rates.

Comment: Yes, and thank you for your answer. And I'm sorry I insist in this issue, I'm just trying to figure out what's the difference between these two algorithm. And what I mean by saying that the solution is not reasonable ia because this solution keeps growing if I increase the iterations. I found the octave code for fminunc and apparently it uses BFGS and trust-region line search. Maybe this avoids the overfitting. I'll try to understand how this works and I'll share my results here. Thanks again for giving your opinion in this question.